# Default scheduling in OpenMP (gcc compiler)

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp

I am using OpenMP in a C++ progam. According to the gcc documentation, the default scheduling is `dynamic` with a chunk size of 1 -> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/libgomp.pdf (p22).

I decided to test this so I wrote a simple C++ test program:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<double>  myArray {};
    for(std::size_t i {0} ; i < 100000000 ; ++i)
    {
        myArray.push_back(static_cast<double>(i));
    }

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Number of threads = " << omp_get_num_threads() << "/" << omp_get_num_procs() << std::endl;
            omp_sched_t schedule {};
            int chunk_size {};
            omp_get_schedule(&schedule , &chunk_size);
            std::string scheduleStr {};
            switch(schedule)
            {
                case omp_sched_static:
                    scheduleStr = "static";
                    break;
                case omp_sched_dynamic:
                    scheduleStr = "dynamic";
                    break;
                case omp_sched_guided:
                    scheduleStr = "guided";
                    break;
                case omp_sched_auto:
                    scheduleStr = "auto";
                    break;
                default:
                    scheduleStr = "monotonic";
                    break;
            }
            std::cout << "Default schedule: " << scheduleStr << "," << chunk_size << std::endl;;
        }
    }

    auto startTime {std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(dynamic, 1)
    for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < myArray.size() ; ++i)
    {
        myArray[i] = std::pow(myArray[i], 10);
    }
    auto endTime {std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
    auto ellapsedTime {std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime)};
    std::cout << "OMP for Time: " << static_cast<double>(ellapsedTime.count())/1000.0 << " s" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code using MSYS2's mingw version (gcc 9.3.0) with no optimisations and `-g` enabled. The default schedule is `dynamic, 1` as in the documentation. However, the computation times on my computer are (with 2 threads):

- with `schedule(static)` : ~2.103s
- with `schedule(dynamic, 1)` : ~24.096s
- omitting `schedule` (should be `dynamic, 1`) : ~2.101s

So that the default schedule seems to be `static`! I know I am asking a very specific question, but is it an intended behaviour ?

Comment: I didnt find any mentioning of default scheduling in the document you linked.

Comment: p 22:
3.12 OMP_SCHEDULE– How threads are scheduled
Description:Allows to specify schedule type and chunk size.  The value of the variable shall  have  the  form:type[,chunk] where type is  one  of static,dynamic,guided or auto. The optional chunk size shall be a positive integer. If undefined,dynamic scheduling and a chunk size of 1 is used.

Comment: As far as I understand OMP_SCHEDULE is used as schedule for omp for loop if no schedule keyword is specifed.

Comment: Then I do not understand what the gcc doc says, if it is not the famous "implementation specific" default schedule. Why specify the default chunk size for `dynamic` but not `static` for example ?

Comment: The GCC documentation is like a quest in a detective comptuer game. You start from the documentation of `OMP_SCHEDULE`, then go to the documentation of `omp_set_schedule`, notice the phrase `runtime scheduling method`, check the OpenMP documentation, find out that there is actually a schedule called `runtime` and that is what `OMP_SCHEDULE` and `omp_set_schedule()` affect, and in five simple steps your problem is resolved.

Comment: By the way, there is an OpenMP construct for `if(omp_get_thread_num() == 0)`: `#pragma omp master`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OMP_SCHEDULE` and `omp_set_schedule()` affect *runtime* loop scheduling, that is `for` constructs with `schedule(runtime)` clause. With most OpenMP runtimes, the default scheduling when no `schedule` clause is present is `static` with chunk size equal to `#iterations / #threads` (the handling of the case where `#threads` does not divide `#iterations` is implementation-specific, but usually the remainder of the iterations is spread over the first `#iterations % #threads` threads). No sane OpenMP vendor would choose `dynamic,1` as the default in that case, given the overhead it entails.

Comment: Indeed it makes more sense like this! ^^

Comment: You can easily see what it's doing (if you can read a bit of assembly code), just use compiler explorer to look, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Vm3zBG where you can see the compiler calling the runtime to get the number of threads and the local thread number.

Comment: p.s. Note that the default schedule is often not exactly a static schedule with chunk #iterations/#numthreads, since it is normally balanced better than that, so that if there are "spare" iterations (i.e. the #iterations % #numthreads != 0) those are handed out one each to the first remainder threads, ensuring that the imbalance in iterations between threads is at most one, rather than up up #numthreads-1 which chunking would require...

Comment: @JimCownie, yeah, that's a detail that I skipped.

Comment: @HristoIliev Sure, no big deal, just trying to ensure that if someone looks at this later they get full information!

Answer (score -1):

> p 22: 3.12 OMP_SCHEDULE– How threads are scheduled Description:Allows to specify schedule type and chunk size. The value of the variable shall have the form:type[,chunk] where type is one of static,dynamic,guided or auto. The optional chunk size shall be a positive integer. If undefined,dynamic scheduling and a chunk size of 1 is used.

This section you quote from is about environment variables. If the environment variable is undefined then dynamic scheduling and a chunk size of 1 is used. In your code you do not check the value or existance of that environment variable but only the actual scheduling strategy. If you do check your environment variable then I would expect that it does exist and is set to static. How you do this depends on the OS (`printenv` in linux).

Comment: According to the windows terminal, by just running `echo %OMP_SCHEDULE%`, I just get... `%OMP_SCHEDULE%`, so the environment variable is undefined and dynamic scheduling should be used.

Comment: @ImperatorS79 I have to admit, I am not too convinced that my asnwer is correct myself, it was just too long for a comment. Though if it is linux you need `echo "$OMP_SCHEDULE"`

Comment: @ImperatorS79 i dont know on windows, but  if `echo %OMP_SCHEDULE%` only prints `%OMP_SCHEDULE%` then it is probably wrong. If the envvariable is not defined echoing it should print nothing

Comment: Well, when I do echo %PATH% I have the path... I will check this ^^.

Comment: Using `set` alone, which list all the environment variables in the current "shell", I do not find OMP_SCHEDULE...